# Error al mostrar iconos escritorio e imágenes luego de actualización raspberry pi 3 (raspbian)

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

Luego de correr la siguiente actualización y reiniciar la raspberry:

```
Start-Date: 2018-01-21  22:54:38
Commandline: apt-get dist-upgrade
Upgrade: ncurses-term:armhf (5.9+20140913-1, 5.9+20140913-1+deb8u2), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:armhf (2.31.1-2+deb8u6, 2.31.1-2+deb8u7), libirs-export91:armhf (9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u14, 9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u15), libdns-export100:armhf (9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u14, 9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u15), libxml2:armhf (2.9.1+dfsg1-5+deb8u5, 2.9.1+dfsg1-5+deb8u6), libisccc90:armhf (9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u14, 9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u15), libisc-export95:armhf (9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u14, 9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u15), libisc95:armhf (9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u14, 9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u15), libbind9-90:armhf (9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u14, 9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u15), libdns100:armhf (9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u14, 9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u15), liblwres90:armhf (9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u14, 9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u15), gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:armhf (2.31.1-2+deb8u6, 2.31.1-2+deb8u7), libisccfg90:armhf (9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u14, 9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u15), mysql-common:armhf (5.5.57-0+deb8u1, 5.5.59-0+deb8u1), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common:armhf (2.31.1-2+deb8u6, 2.31.1-2+deb8u7), libmysqlclient18:armhf (5.5.57-0+deb8u1, 5.5.59-0+deb8u1), bind9-host:armhf (9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u14, 9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u15), libisccfg-export90:armhf (9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u14, 9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u15), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev:armhf (2.31.1-2+deb8u6, 2.31.1-2+deb8u7)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2018-01-21  22:56:03
```

Dejó de mostrar todos los íconos y también si intento abrir una imagen cualquiera ya sea .png .jpg etc. dice: "No se pudo reconocer el formato de imagen del archivo nombreArchivo.png"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de por qué pasó esto y cómo lo podría solucionar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné con:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo restart
```